# How can I put the @ symbol in an html page? What is the entity?

Tags: html

I am a student and brand new to HTML. We are making websites and I am trying to figure out how to code the "@" symbol into my page.

I originally in one of my paragraphs wrote "The game is located @ etc." But I want to put it as "The game is located (@ entity) etc"

Comment: You want what? Can you clarify what an `@ entity` is and how its different from the character?

Comment: The @ symbol, I want to know how to code the utf-8 code equivalent for the @ symbol

Comment: Why can't you just use the character?

Comment: @j08691 That's &, not @. @ is `&#64;`. Which the OP could look up with [a simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+entity+for+at+symbol)

Comment: @tkausl - Unicode has more than one `@` symbol. It has `@` (standard), `＠` (full-width) and `﹫` (small). Only the standard `@` is available from the keyboard.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Character references are useful when the character you want to use

- has special meaning in HTML
- does not appear in ASCII (and you are stuck on an 20th century system that doesn't use UTF-8)
- doesn't appear on a standard keyboard so it hard to type (but copy/pasting is still usually a better bet)
- could be confused with another similar looking character (e.g. a space vs a non-breaking space)

None of those apply to the @ symbol. You should just type `@`.

That said, if you really want to use an entity, it is:

```html
&commat;
```

It takes 8 characters (and bytes) instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

As ***@Quentin*** has already indicated, you can use the HTML escape `&commat;` which is the same as both `&#64;` and simply typing `@` on your keyboard and is represented in **Unicode** as `U+0040`.

However, there are, *additionally*, two more `at` symbols in **Unicode**, *full-width* and *small*:

- `U+FF20`
- `U+FE6B`

For which the HTML escapes are:

- `&#65312;`
- `&#65131;`

---

**Example:**

```html
<h2>Standard <code>@</code> symbols</h2>
<ul>
<li>@ <code>[TYPED FROM KEYBOARD]</code></li>
<li>&commat; <code>[&amp;commat;]</code></li>
<li>&#64; <code>[&amp;#64;]</code></li>
</ul>

<h2>Alternative <code>@</code> symbols</h2>
<ul>
<li>&#65312; <code>[&amp;#65312;]</code> <em>full-width</em></li>
<li>&#65131; <code>[&amp;#65131;]</code> <em>small</em></li>
</ul>
```